# curl command in node using npm request

Tags: node.js, curl, npm, request

I want to make a post curl command with npm request

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Authorization: Basic Random key' -H 'On-Behalf-Of: user_ID' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"first_name" : "first", "last_name": "last"}' 'https://randomapi.com'
```

but when I try to use the npm request like so:

```
app.get("/add/prospect/", (req,res) => {
    var firstName = "first";
    var lastName = "last";
    var formData = {
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName
    }
    var url = "https://randomapi.com";
    var options = {
        method: "POST",
        url:url,
        data: formData,
        json:true,
        headers: {
            "Authorization" : "Basic " + new Buffer(api_key + ":").toString("base64"),
            "On-Behalf-Of": user_id,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.json(response);
    })
})
```

I am getting a 404 resource not found error

```
"statusCode": 404,
  "body": {
    "message": "Resource not found"
  },
```

it works when I use the curl method but npm request its not working, anything I am missing?

Comment: Please check the URL as the curl request is also returning 404 error

Comment: oh i replaced the urls with an example url. The actual curl command with the url - https://harvest.greenhouse.io/v1/prospects/ would need an api key, but it works.